# Transform an instruction from a css to jquery

Tags: jquery

Good morning. 
I would like to make a statement css:

```
#menu > ul > li:hover > ul
```

in a jquery.

How would? 
Thank you. Dave

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('#menu > ul > li').mouseenter(function(){
   currntul= $('ul',this);
});
```